# Rename [halo-mcc] → [halo-the-master-chief-collection]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Thanks to our 35 character limit, we can now fit the whole name of the *[Halo: The Master Chief Collection](http://halo-mcc)*.

Can we rename [halo-mcc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-mcc) → [halo-the-master-chief-collection](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-the-master-chief-collection)?

I'm not sure that a synonym of the old one needs to be kept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Done:**

- [halo-mcc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-mcc) → [halo-the-master-chief-collection](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-the-master-chief-collection)